# Compactly supported continous function on given set

Tags: analysis, compactness

Let $K \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a compact and convex set, is there a function with Support K that is continous?

I know this claim does not hold if $K$ only Compact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the interval $K = [0, 1] \subseteq \mathbb{R} \subseteq \mathbb{C}$. $K$ is compact since it is closed and bounded, and it is clearly convex. However, there is no continuous function $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ having support $K$, since for some $k \in K$ we would have $f(k) \neq 0$, but $f(k + i\epsilon) = 0$ for all $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: Maybe nonempty interior (together with compactness and convexity) could be enough?

Comment: @szw1710 Yes, I think this would be enough. A compact convex set $X$ with nonempty interior is homeomorphic to the closed unit disc $D$, and in fact there is a homeomorphism $g: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ which will send $X$ to $D$. It should be obvious that continuous functions with support $D$ exist.